# Is this an abnormal pattern in SE?

Tags: discussion, up-votes, serial-voting

Lately I’ve been observing something weird with my SE profile, each time I post a question in SO, I’m getting up-votes in my other SE related profiles, in particular the most up-voted questions.

Is this normal in SE, or there is a chance that someone could be keeping track of my activity to do such thing like creating a new account an up-voting the top questions in my account profile?

Comment: This is not normal, that's for sure.

Comment: *Creating a new account* and up-voting your top questions doesn't seem to be plausible due to the necessary rep of 150 to upvote.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a chance it is just be a coincidence, your most upvoted answers may be attracting positive attention.  But, the repeating pattern seems peculiar.

Perhaps contact the team ('Contact Us' tab) stating what is happening, they have the tools to see if something odd is going on.